# __dirname not Defined Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I am learning how to build Electron Applications, and I can't understand why I keep getting this error to print the current directory of my folder. Can someone explain ?

I tried to review some online articles on this but haven't been able to understand

MY Html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bookmark</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Bookmark</h1>
    <button class = "alert" onclick="dir()">Click here</button>
    <script>
        const button = document.querySelector('.alert');
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert(__dirname);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My main.js

```
const {path} = require('path');
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Hello from Electron");
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
    mainWindow.webContents.loadFile(`index.html`);
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "bookmark",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^25.0.1"
  }
}
```

FYI, I am learning through reading a book on building desktop applications with Electron, and I think it is pretty outdated. Can someone suggest better material in 2023 ?

Comment: [Official documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-prerequisites) is always a good place to start and can actually answer most general problems. Please also read [ask] – asking for off-site resources is actually off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You should treat a renderer process (the process that runs your html page) as a browser window with just a few extra hooks. It used to be more open, but over the years Electron has tightened up its security model.

See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model where about halfway down it says:

> Renderer processes can be spawned with a full Node.js environment for ease of development. Historically, this used to be the default, but this feature was disabled for security reasons.

One way to get the current directory and show it in the renderer process would be to IPC between it and the main process. See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc for the various approaches.

I'd avoid books and tutorials that don't talk about using preload scripts and contextBridge as being out of date. And avoid anything written for Electron 13 or earlier.